# App bluetooth classic not scan device when upgrade android 5.1 to 6.0 ( not BLE)

Tags: android, bluetooth, scanning

I have not found a way can make it work.
How to scan device bluetooth on android 6.0.
Here my code

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device =     intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed     already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" +     device.getAddress());
            }
            // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if     (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices =     getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Manifest.xml
   app have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```